# App iOS with prestashop webview

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store-connect, prestashop

I am new to iOS programming and I know very little about their admissions policy applications. I have an application made ​​in phonegap and there is a section where if you click menu, shown inside a shop made an iframe in prestashop. I wonder if the fact of having a store within an app without having to iTunes connect iOS is cause for rejection.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it depends on whether you sell physical or digital goods.

Digital goods have to be sold via Apple's "In App purchase" (IAP) and are charged with a 30% commission.

Physical goods cannot be purchased by IAP and thus you're forced to provide a different payment method (like PayPal), hence not paying the IAP commission.

So long story short: if you sell psysical goods, your app will not be rejected for providing another payment method than IAP.

For further information please read here: https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf